# Possible to let users consent to another (or multiple) Azure app service (web app or api) access their account data?

Tags: azure-active-directory, access-token, azure-web-app-service

I am working on creating 2 app services in Azure. 1 web app and 1 web api.

My goal is to sign in users to their personal or Office 365 school or work account, and let the api access their personal account data, like the calendar.

However, it's the web app that signs in the users because I need a web site (GUI) to let them do that. The web app will display a sign in prompt, letting users sign in.

How can I then let the web api (a different app service) get access to their personal data when it's the web app that signs them in?

My plan was to sign them in through the web app, and then share the access token with the api which resides in a different app service. In that way I figured the api would have access. I hope this work, but I started thinking the api might not get access if the token is made only to let the web app (site) get access.

Is it possible to prompt the users to consent to 2 different app services getting access to their data?

Answer (score 0):

Your scenario seems like web application signing in users, calling a Web API with the user's identity.

You can refer to [this document](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect-aspnetcore) for the detailed steps.

Comment: It's close, in the sense that I need both a web application and web api (and the link provided some useful info). However, I think I would not need the web application to call the web api. My intention is for the web api to make authenticated calls to Microsoft Graph, having been authenticated via the web application (I thought that I might share the access token via a shared table). I might detail my scenario more in a follow up reply to this thread.

Comment: @Morten I see, what you were talking about is onbehalfof flow(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow). You can refer to this sample. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v1-code#web-api-calling-microsoft-graph-or-another-web-api